# Appium driver running multiple tests at once?

Tags: selenium, junit, appium

Can a single instance of AppiumDriver run multiple different tests at once?

I have two tests in a single class like so:

```
public class mainTest {


    @Test 
    public void mainMenu(){

    }

    @Test 
    public void goToViews() {

    }


}
```

Can a single driver instance run both of these tests (which are on a native app) at the same time (concurrently)? Or would I need a separate driver instance for each test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NO**

If you want to run tests in parallel, you need a **unique Appium session for each concurrent test** and it means you need to have **Appium driver instances as much**, as you have **tests in parallel**.

The good part is that you can have **multiple Appium sessions** on **single Appium server instance**.

Answer (score 0):

The above both test case will run but I suggest you to use **testng** for appium testing. You can control all your testcase from the single xml file. TestNG is designed to cover all categories of tests:  unit, functional, end-to-end, integration, etc...